# Origin-Destination Table join

Tags: sql

How to `join` the following tables? Or is this possible?

Column `origin` and `destination` is fk.

```
**tbleroute**
ID      ORIGIN        DESTINATION
1         1                 3
2         1                 2
3         3                 4

**tblelocation**
ID       Name
1        Bus Station
2        Market
3        Bus Station 2
4        School
```

Comment: Join tblelocation twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the obvious result, you need two joins.  This looks like:

```
select r.*, lo.name as origin_name, ld.name as destination_name
from tblrouter r join
     tbllocation lo
     on r.origin = lo.id join
     tbllocation ld
     on r.destination = ld.id;
```

This is a situation where table aliases are needed in the `from` clause to distinguish the tables.